# SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA - regulating how often this event is tirggered

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I is to possible to regulate how often flash triggers SAMPLE_DATA event when sampling data from input device ? I need to sample constantly (even silence).

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
```

AFAIK currently this function gets called 20 times/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

playing with the sample code from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
function sineWaveGenerator(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
    for ( var c:int=0; c<8192; c++ ) {
        event.data.writeFloat(Math.sin((Number(c+event.position)/Math.PI/2))*0.25);
        event.data.writeFloat(Math.sin((Number(c+event.position)/Math.PI/2))*0.25);
    }
}

mySound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA,sineWaveGenerator);
mySound.play();
```

the less data you write, the more often the method gets called.

if you call it too often the sound may get clicky and gross.  try adjusting the frame rate.